# ¿Cuáles son todas las formas correctas para añadir todas las implementaciones de favicons?

Tags: html, html5

Solo conozco una implementación del favicon:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" 
 href="../static/img/favicon.ico">
```

Pero esto no me esta funcionando cuando uso Safari en Mac OS X en la pantalla en la que salen los favicons favoritos en grande ni en Android cuando añado un acceso en la pantalla de inicio, lo único que me sale en estos casos es una letra.

Quisiera saber cuales son las formas para implementarlo en estos dos últimos.

Comment: No se si es algo "estándar" en Safari, pero esta [respuesta](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/233269) te puede ayudar en tu investigación.

Comment: Una opción a las respuestas dadas es usar un generador automático. Funciona bastante bien y es configurable a partir de iconos svg, png... hay muchos, uno de los que suelo usar es este: [realfavicongenerator](http://realfavicongenerator.net/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo he resuelto de la siguiente manera: Como ha dicho Oscar R en el comentario, he usado una pagina que genera a partir de una imagen todas las etiquetas necesarias para todos los OS.

[La página que he usado es: http://realfavicongenerator.net/](http://realfavicongenerator.net/)

Funciona muy bien, y me ha funcionado como he dicho en todos los OS, además después permite checkear si todo funciona correctamente una vez hecho el deploy introduciendo la url de tu sitio. Y te da las imágenes preparadas para descargar e implementar.

Answer (score 1):

Intenta usar como .png

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/img/favicon.png" type="image/png">
```

Intenta los iconos para apple-touch-icon:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="https://cdn.css-tricks.com/apple-touch-icon-57x57.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="https://cdn.css-tricks.com/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="https://cdn.css-tricks.com/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="https://cdn.css-tricks.com/apple-touch-icon-144x144.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="https://cdn.css-tricks.com/apple-touch-icon-60x60.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="https://cdn.css-tricks.com/apple-touch-icon-120x120.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="https://cdn.css-tricks.com/apple-touch-icon-76x76.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="https://cdn.css-tricks.com/apple-touch-icon-152x152.png">
```

Comment: ya te puse los iconos de apple-touch-icon con esos debe de funcionar.

Comment: No, no funciona.

Comment: podrías poner tu html completo para ver el posible problema?

Answer (score 0):

Tienes varias formas de hacerlo y con varios formatos

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="imagen.png" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/gif" href="imagen.gif" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/icono.icon" href="imagen.ico" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="image/icono.icon">
```

Puedes Utilizar varios tamaños depende de tu situación:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="imagen_16.png" sizes="16x16" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="imagen_32.png" sizes="32x32" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="imagen_64.png" sizes="64x64" />
```

HTML 5 fue la primera en definir los favicons, añadiendo  el atributo sizes, para indicar los tamaños de las imágenes

> (para imágenes escalables, como SVG, se puede utilizar el valor any)

Aquí te dejo información: [How to Add a Favicon to your Site - W3C](https://www.w3.org/2005/10/howto-favicon).